# Generating test-result report in Endly for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, end-to-end, endly

How do I generate an XML test result report in Endly for parsing and viewing in Jenkins?

Comment: welcome to SO! what have you tried so far? please also get familiar with [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is the "-x" parameter that I didn't see before.

-x string
        xunit summary report format: xml|yaml|json